# Hide split horizontal symbol when mouse hovering over QSplitter

Tags: qt

I am using `QSplitter` to split two widgets but between them, there is a QSplitter sign shown. How can I disable or hide it? Or normally show the cursor as it used somewhere?

[image]

I don't want to see this horizontal Splitter as it is not used in the widget.

Comment: If I understand, you want to disable the double arrow when hovering the widget ?

Comment: right my requirement is to disable double arrow when arrow reaches at the location Indicated in the Image.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need that mouse dragging functionality at all, you can call `setWidgetAttribute(WA_TransparentForMouseEvents);` on the splitter. I think that should help !?

Answer (score 0):

You must reimplement the protected method `QSplitterHandle *QSplitter::createHandle()` of your splitter, and inside it, you create your own handler with the desired cursor :

```
QSplitterHandle *MySplitter::createHandle()
{
    QSplitterHandle *handler(new QSplitterHandle(Qt::Orientation::Horizontal /*for example*/, this));
    handler->setCursor(Qt::ArrowCursor);
    return handler;
}
```